# Inserting NULL value to a double data type MySQL Python

Tags: python, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a table. This is the create statement.

```
   CREATE TABLE `runsettings` (
  `runnumber` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `equipment` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `wafer` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `settingname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `float8value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `apcrunid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `intvalue` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `floatvalue` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Batch` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IndexNum` smallint(6) DEFAULT '1',
  `stringvalue` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1056989 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is my insert statement :

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='test',
                                password ='test',host='0.0.0.1',
                              database='test')


vallist = [(471285, u'CT19', 7, u'271042', u'Etch Time Min', None, None, None),
           (471285, u'CT19', 7, u'00000', u'Etch Time Min', None, None, 'None')]


cursor = cnx.cursor()
# ss = 

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO runsettings (apcrunid,equipment,runnumber,wafer,settingname,intvalue,floatvalue,float8value) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",vallist)
cnx.commit()
```

So I try to insert these values .

```
vallist = [471285, u'CT19', 7, u'271042', u'Etch Time Min', None, None, None,
           471285, u'CT19', 7, u'00000', u'Etch Time Min', None, None, 'None']
```

This is getting inserted. 
Result on DB
[image]
But when the list value is this one (difference is the string `'None'` gets evaluated first):

```
vallist = [471285, u'CT19', 7, u'271042', u'Etch Time Min', None, None, 'None', 
           471285, u'CT19', 7, u'271042', u'Etch Time Min', None, None, None]
```

It gives out the truncated error.

```
Data truncated for column 'float8value' at row 2
```

How come when the row that contains `None` is the first on the list  it doesn't give out the same truncated error on the first list?

Comment: I am pretty sure that is the query i am executing. Its also weird that a 0 value is getting inserted on that column.

Comment: actually either of the methods (prepared or not) gives me the same result on the database, so lets use the latest one (not prepared).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not entirely suprising. In the first instance you are inserting the python predefined constant [None](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html)

> The sole value of types.NoneType. None is frequently used to represent
>   the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not passed to a
>   function.

That equates to SQL `NULL`. In the second instance you are inserting a String called 'None' into the table. These two are very different. If you insert a string into a double or float field you will see all kinds of errors, most often, the exact one you have seen.

in the first instance it works because you have declared :

```
 `float8value` double DEFAULT NULL,
```

This accepts NULL and None is in the 8th place in your values list. When lots of different parameters are being used, it's always a good idea to use named parameters so that it's obvious at a glance what's being bound to each column.

Updates:

After running your code, the only conclusion that can be reached is that you have found a bug, by using `print(cursor.statement)` it's possible to discover that the executed query is.

```
INSERT INTO runsettings (apcrunid,equipment,runnumber,wafer,settingname,intvalue,floatvalue,float8value) 
VALUES (471285,'CT19',7,'271042','Etch Time Min',NULL,NULL,NULL),
       (471285,'CT19',7,'00000','Etch Time Min',NULL,NULL,'None')
```

This does not produce an error, but if you erase the first set of values the error is indeed produced. My recommendation is to file a bug report

Comment: I am aware of that, the question is how come the first list got inserted without any error? How come it did not catch `'None'` value on the second set of row?

Comment: okay so on the first vallist - > Those values got accepted. two rows have been inserted on the table.

Comment: im pretty sure thats the query, i only have 4 lines of code. Which includes the list and the query.

Comment: thank you for clarifying @e4c5! i will try to send a bug report to mysql

Comment: glad to have been of help